# Exports and require scope in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

fighting for 5 days with the problem.
I have 3 files, needed to share one varible kvmIndex between them

**getKvmIndex.js**

```
var kvmIndex=[],
exports.kvmIndex = kvmIndex;
exports.getSNMP = function (callback) {
   async.each(switchIps, function(switchIp, callback1) {
   goGo(switchIp, callback1);
   }, function(err) {
        callback();
    })
};
```

**match.js**

```
var app1 = require("./app.js");
var kvmIndex;
exports.kvmIndex = kvmIndex;
...

exports.matchAll = function(callback) {
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        kvmIndex = app1.kvmIndex;
        decToHex(callback);
    },
    function(callback){
        matchSt('getPortToSt2', callback);
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log(kvmIndex);    //Here it defined! Works good.
        callback()
    }
])
callback();
}
```

**app.js**

```
var kvmSNMP = require('./getKvmIndex')
, match = require('./match')
, async = require('async')
, kvmIndex = [];
...
async.series([
function(callback) {
    kvmSNMP.getSNMP(callback);
},
function(callback) {
    exports.kvmIndex = kvmSNMP.kvmIndex;
    callback();
},
function(callback) {
    match.matchAll(callback);
},
function (callback) {
    kvmIndex = match.kvmIndex;
    callback();
},
function (callback) {
    console.log(match.kvmIndex); //Doesnt work(
    callback();
}
])
```

What i'm doing:

- Define blank variable
- Export it
- Doing stuff with it globally
- Accessing it in app.js

In **getKvmIndex.js** it works fine, but in **match.js** no.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `kvmIndex` in one module (file) and one only. It that module, add to it `exports` like you do. The other modules (files) need to `require` the module defining `kvmIndex`, and use it by accessing `myModule.kvmIndex`.

Notes:

1) It would be nicer to export `getKvmIndex()` from `getKvmIndex.js`, and not the variable `kvmIndex` directly.

2) You may have a bug in `match.js` -- the callback is called immediately. Did you maybe mean to pass `callback` and the 2nd argument to `async.series()` ?

Comment: TU for answer, Nitzan,
 I'm working with kvmIndex in both files - getKvmIndex.js and match.js and use it globally. So I should define it blank. I understand, globals is evil, but I think it simplier for now.
How can use it properly to 
1. Do tasks in getKvmIndex.js
2. Export results into app.js
3. Import results from app.js to match.js
4. To tasks in match.js
5. Export result to app.js
By having just only kvmIndex defined globally.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I already explained: defined `kvmIndex` in only *one* file, say `kvmIndex.js`. If you want to use it in other files (like `match.js` and `app.js`) in those files just do: `kvmModule = require("./getKvmIndex");` and then use `kvmModule.kvmIndex`. No need to export anything from `match.js` or from `app.js`.